# Replace the string/line after separator on specific param

Tags: linux, perl, solaris

I have the following Perl one liner code ,

My target is to replace the line after “=” separator, and that defined in **PARAM** variable

```
more file.txt
PARAM=I WANT TO REPLACE THIS LINE

bash-3.00# export VAL="THIS IS THE NEW LINE FOR EXAMPLE"
bash-3.00# perl -i -pe 's/(PARAM=)+/${*}$ENV{VAL}/' file.txt
bash-3.00# more file.txt
THIS IS THE NEW LINE FOR EXAMPLEI WANT TO REPLACE THIS LINE
```

But actually its replace all the line include the PARAM itself

The expected results should be

```
more file.txt
PARAM= THIS IS THE NEW LINE FOR EXAMPLE
```

Please advice what need to fix in my Perl one liner code?

other example that still not work:

```
bash-3.00# more file.txt
PARAM=SOME STRING
bash-3.00# export VAL="PUT THAT"
bash-3.00# perl -i -pe 's/PARAM=\K.+/$ENV{VAL}/' file.txt
bash-3.00# more file.txt
PARAM=SOME STRING
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\K` (positive look behind) and `.+` to remove everything after `PARAM=` until newline,

```
perl -i -pe 's/PARAM=\K.+/ $ENV{VAL}/' file.txt
```

or for older perl,

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=PARAM=).+/ $ENV{VAL}/' file.txt
```

Comment: I test it and its not replace the new VAL with the old VAL

Comment: sorry but I not see any changes on your code? , what the diff , its still not work ( why the space between "/" to "$" ?

Comment: yes I did it and it still not replace the old str , what your perl version?

Comment: I have perl - This is perl, v5.8.7 built for sun4-solaris-thread-multi

Comment: YES I ALREADY UPVORE YOUR ANSWER AFTER I SEE IT AND I CHOOSE YOUR SOLUTION , if you can please upvote my question I think my question is agood one